# Why is it not possible to store a function pointer of a base class?

Tags: c++, function-pointers

The following code gives an compilation error for `void b() { m = &A::a; };` stating that `A::a()` is protected. (Which it is - but that should be no problem)
However the compiler doesn't care when I write `B::a()`. Even though both mean the same I would prefer `A::a()` because it states explicitely that `a()` is defined in A.

So **what is the reason why `A::a()` is forbidden**?
**EDIT**
Maybe someone can find an example that would be problematic if `A::a()` was allowed in `B::b()`. If there is such an example, I will mark it as answer to the question.
**/EDIT**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>

class A {
protected:
  void a(){ std::cout << "A::a()" << std::endl; };
};

typedef void (A::*f)();
class B : public A {
public:
  void b() { m = &A::a; }; // wont compile
  // void b() { m = &B::a; }; // works fine
  void c() { (this->*m)(); };
protected:
  f m;
};

int main(){
  B b;
  b.b();
  b.c();
}

// compile with
// g++ -Wall main.cpp -o main
```

Explanation of the code:
In B I want to store a function pointer to a method in A to be able to call that later in `B::c()`. And yes, this happens in real life too. :-)

Comment: Amusing... happens both with `gcc-3.4.2` and `gcc-4.3.2`

Comment: may be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477829/cannot-call-base-class-protected-functions/477868#477868

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason should be similar to why you can't do this in B either:

```
class B: public A
{
    //...
    void foo(A& x) {
        x.a(); //error
    }

    void foo(B& x) {
        x.a(); //OK
    }
};
```

That **protected** doesn't mean that B can access the A part of any class as long it is an A / derived from A. The protected stuff is only available for this and other instances of B.

Answer (score 2):

Because otherwise the outside world can find this protected member: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=11174.

See also http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2004-06/msg00610.html.

Comment: Hmm, in my ignorance I still can't see why it is necessary. The function-pointer and thus the method is still protected in B. So it is not accessible from outside and if it was so would `B::b()` or am I missing the point completely?

Comment: @tuner07, access protection is determined by the static type of the expression. The actual context in which you take the function-pointer doesn't come into play.

Comment: @gf If the access protection is determined by the static type of the expression it shouldn't be possible to call `A::a()` anywhere in B. But that is possible. So the rule applies only to the case where a function is stored into a function-pointer. I can still see no reason why `A::a()` must be prevented by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You try to access protected member through global namespace (A::a is ::A::a here), use B::A::a instead.