# Accessing element in an object in C++ OOPS

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance, new-operator

I am learning OOPS in C++. I try to access the class data member using pointer. But it throws error.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A

{
    protected:
        int x;
    public:
        A()
        {
            x=10;
        }
};

class B:public A
{
   public:
   void out()
   {
       A *p=new A;
       cout<<p->x;
   }
};

int main()
{
   B b;
   b.out();
   return 0;
}
```

The above code gives error as

```
error: ‘int A::x’ is protected within this context
    |        cout<<p->x;
```

Can anyone explain why the error occurs? The expected output is to print the value of x. Thanks in advance.

Comment: *The expected output is to print the value of x.* Why is it expected?

Comment: You create a *new* object in the `out` function. That object is unrelated to the `this` object. You can only access protected members of `this` object.

Comment: Also, remember that in C++ you don't have to (and rarely should) use `new` to create objects. By using `new` you have a memory leak.

Comment: Also please note that objects should rarely be just containers of values. Try to model your classes and inheritance hierarchy on *behavior*.

Comment: This is a more basic error, so not a direct duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13723217/why-cant-i-access-a-protected-member-variable-of-a-base-class-passed-into-a-fun/13723325#13723325. But the answer given there applies here as well. `B::out` can access the protected member of its base class `A` sub-object, but not that of an unrelated `*p` object.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in this code is related to pointers  and making class objects. In the *void out()* function of class B, you used dynamic memory allocation (i.e. *new A*) to create an object of class A, and then tried to access the **protected** '*x*' member of class A. Since B is an inherited class, it can access the *x* member. However, since the object you created in class B (*new A*) is of class type A, the protected member is not accessible outside the class. So it ends up showing a compilation error.
The problem is also that the *out()* function creates a new A object and it prints the value of *x* from this new object, not from the B object.

To fix this, you should directly access the x member from the object of class B, as it is derived from class A and can access its protected members. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
protected:
    int x;

public:
    A()
    {
        x = 10;
    }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    void out()
    {
        // Access the 'x' member of the current 'B' object
        cout << x;
    }
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    b.out();
    return 0;
}
```

I hope this helps.