# Why can't we call protected destructors from a derived class?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, c++11, destructor

I'm aware of the uses of private (and of course public) destructors.

I'm also aware of the uses of a protected destructor in a derived class:

> Use a protected destructor to prevent the destruction of a derived object via a base-class pointer

But I've tried running the following code and it won't compile:

```
struct A{
    int i;
    A() { i = 0;}
    protected: ~A(){}
};

struct B: public A{
    A* a;
    B(){ a = new A();}
    void f(){ delete a; }
};


int main()
{
   B b= B();
   b.f();
   return 0;
}
```

I get:

```
void B::f()':
main.cpp:9:16: error: 'A::~A()' is protected
```

What am I missing?

If I called a protected method in A from inside f() it would work. So why is calling the d'tor different?

Comment: I guess this is a duplicate, you can't call protected member functions of base class objects other than `*this` in a derived class' member function.

Comment: Related or duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13723217/420683

Comment: possible duplicate of [cannot call base class protected functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477829/cannot-call-base-class-protected-functions)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`protected` doesn't mean that your `B` can access the members of *any* `A`; it only means that it can access those members of its own `A` base... and members of some other `B`'s `A` base!

This is in contrast to `private`, whereby some object with type `A` can always invoke the `private` members of *another* object with type `A`.

Comment: A member function of class `B` can also access the protected members declared in class `A` of another object, given that this object is of type `B` or derived from `B`. It's quite confusing.

Comment: I shall `public`ly upvote you in a `protected` fashion. Wanna meet in `private` later?

Comment: @DyP: Oh, yes, that's true.

Comment: So, what happens in a polymorphic scenario where the `A*` is actually used to allocate a `B` instance during the runtime - `B` doesn't know whether the actual instance is of type A or B? A no go because of using a base pointer even though it is a B instance?

Comment: @ddriver: That's right! Virtual dispatch works for function calls but access restrictions are applied first.