# Derived class cannot access the protected member of the base class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, protected

Consider the following example

```
class base
{
protected :
    int x = 5;
    int(base::*g);
};
class derived :public base
{
    void declare_value();
    derived();
};
void derived:: declare_value()
{
    g = &base::x;
}
derived::derived()
    :base()
{}
```

As per knowledge only friends and derived classes of the base class can access the protected members of the base class but in the above example I get the following error `"Error  C2248   'base::x': cannot access protected member declared in class "` but when I add the following line

```
friend class derived;
```

declaring it as friend , I can access the members of the base class , did I do some basic mistake in the declaring the derived class ?

Comment: Well, the constructor of `derived` is private, so the class will be tricky to use, but I don't think that's the problem. Why not try it using a simpler access? For example, a derived class function that just returns `x` (Hint: you won't need to specify `base::` to access it)

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477829/cannot-call-base-class-protected-functions?rq=1 answer your question? It's very similar.

Comment: why to not use just : g = &x; ?

Comment: @SebastianRedl the question you link is about calling a protected method on another instance, which isnt exactly the case here

Comment: @user463035818 The reasoning is the same though. You try to access a protected member through an access path that is not your class. Which is why songyuanyao's answer works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing protected members in a derived class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247671/accessing-protected-members-in-a-derived-class)

Comment: @SebastianRedl I get your point, though i dont think it is that obvious that this applies here, thus I wouldnt flag it as exact duplicate

Comment: That's why I didn't.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The derived class could access the [`protected`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access#Protected_member_access) members of base class only through the context of the derived class. On the other word, the derived class can't access `protected` members through the base class.

> When a pointer to a protected member is formed, it must use a derived
>   class in its declaration:
>
> ```
> struct Base {
>  protected:
>     int i;
> };
>
> struct Derived : Base {
>     void f()
>     {
> //      int Base::* ptr = &Base::i;    // error: must name using Derived
>         int Base::* ptr = &Derived::i; // okay
>     }
> };
> ```

You can change

```
g = &base::x;
```

to

```
g = &derived::x;
```

Comment: @user463035818 `g = &x;`? No. `&x` is with type `int*`, which can't be assigned to pointer to member. [LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/8PDA9WaRD8ojOHjw)

Comment: The *reason* for this is that a derived class is only allowed to access the base protected members for its own type.  Imagine a Shape base class with protected members.  If Square inherits from it, we would not want Square to access the protected members of a Circle.  (Point being, just because X inherits from Base doesn't mean X should have access to all Base protected members, only from those that are actually in use by objects of type X.)  The base::qualification no longer is in the context of a derived class, and so the protected access prevents it.

Comment: there seems to be a difference between `&(foo::x)` and `&foo::x` i wasnt aware of (first is a `int*`, second is a pointer to `int`  member)

Comment: @user463035818 Yes. For this case `&(derived::x)` is same as `&(x)` and `&x`.

Comment: @ChrisUzdavinis I've been thinking this for a while, about *why a derived class member or friend may access the protected members of the base class **only through** a derived object.* And I don't agree with your example. I think the point is, setting `protected` in a class means user could not have access to it from anywhere **outside the class itself**, even if from derived class. Check this [answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/345312/why-is-accessing-virtual-protected-functions-of-a-base-class-not-allowed-through)

Comment: @Rick Protected allows access to members (and friends) of the class that declares it, and also to its derived classes.  What is NOT allowed is if X is a base with a protected member, and two classes A and B both derive from X.  A can see protected member of X only when looking at classes of type A (since it is its own data), but not X's protected members in class B, and vice versa.  Given a pointer to base, you don't know if it actually points to A or B, and so to disallow A from seeing B's protected data (and vice versa) it's just not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

My compiler actually said I needed to add a non-default constructor to `base` because the field is not initialized.

After I added

```
base() : g(&base::x) {}
```

it did compile without problems.

Comment: That's working because you are accessing base::x from inside base, which obviously will have access.

Comment: @ChrisUzdavinis I did not remove any lines, the line that is giving the error in the question is still there and happily compiling without errors. I just fixed the *other* errors by *adding* a constructor.